# React native navigation how to connect it to Redux state?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-native-navigation

I noticed below `navigate` is not updating the Redux state once it's passed to another component even the Redux data is updated.

`navigation.navigate('anotherComponent', { firstname, lastname, loading, onRefresh });`

In `anotherComponent`, 
`this.props.navigation.state.params`
This works fine but does not update the Redux state value once it received the state from previous component. Updating Redux state won't change anything in `anotherComponent`.

How do I make this connect to Redux so `anotherCompoenet` actually updates data when Redux updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can achieve when you connect `anotherComponen` with redux and save information in redux that you want in `anotherComponent`.